# Reporting - 5 layers of Account Hierarchy and their related Objects

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I've tried JOINED Reports but I'm not an expert. Can I do something like this with 1 or more Reports?

Ideally it would support all Child Objects per Account in an Account Hierarchy, as you see in the mock-up. I'm also ok with Account to single Child Object

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Oct 7, 2021
We ended up going with iTools. Small, lean, effective business. I had no affiliation before seeking them out to solve this problem. Super impressed with the customer service. They bend over backwards for their customers.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gFEWEA2

Rollup Helper was less expensive, but too basic for our needs.

---

I received this from my Salesforce Success Manager:
Account Hierarchies are created through Lookup relationships in Salesforce. Because of that, it's not possible to use standard roll-summary fields to create cross-account roll-up values. That said, there are a lot of great resources available through our Success Community and from advanced admins that I think may help:
Steve Mollis' "Ultimate Parent" formula and reporting tip: https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ChkPAAS
Andy Fawecett's open source package available on Github for declarative rollup lookup summaries: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#packaged-release-history
AppExchange solution from Passage Technology (Rollup Helper):
https://www.passagetechnology.com/rollup-helper-use-cases/2014/4/30/eydpg6v602ttc2uacdezcs0i40jyh6

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised they don't include the following in the documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_hierarchy_setup_lex.htm&type=5

In the Hierarchy feature (which can be applied to several objects, not only Account), if you hover any record, a small modal appears, displaying some fields and related lists. This is your object's "Compact View".

To add, remove or reorder fields here, simply go to Object Manager > Object (Account in this case) > Compact View > edit default or clone new > Add, remove or reorder fields.

[image]

From here, this can get powerful. Consider adding Rollup Summary fields to your object. For example, per Account in the Hierarchy, I want to know how many Opportunities on each. Simply create that Rollup field on Account and add it to the Compact View. That's COUNT. You can also some Amount of all Opportunities associated with an Account.

Now, it gets trickier if you want to Rollup across multiple levels of parent and child. It may or may not be possible by adding a farely advanced FORMULA field that adds up everything. Now, I'm considering iTools Hierarchies or Rollup Helper on AppExchange for this more advanced use case. The fields I create with either of these tools, I'll simply add them to the same Compact View.

You can edit the fields shown in this Hierarchy view which is native to Lightning. You can add custom Rollup Summary Fields next to where it shows Type, Phone, etc.

This might help get someone started on figuring out such an advanced formula as I postulated above:

IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.id))
,Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
+ Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.id))
,Parent.Oppty_Amount_Total__c
,111.00
)))))))

Comment: This might help get someone started on figuring out such an advanced formula as I postulated above: